# How copy() php works ? overwritting contents or adds?

Tags: php

i think that don't understand how `copy()` works...

it overwritting the contents of orginal file in destination file or adds the content ?

```
$originale = '/var/www/sito/pagina.php';
$copia = '/var/www/sito_backup/backup_pagina.php';
copy($originale,$copia);
```

Comment: What is the return of `copy()` from your script?

Comment: **Doc:** The `copy()` function copies a file. This function returns TRUE on success and FALSE on failure. [func_filesystem_copy.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_copy.asp)

Comment: **Note:** If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.

Comment: overwritten also if the name of destination file is not the same ? and each time run file where is copy() ? yes ?

Comment: What part of the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) you don't understand? Your question is unclear. *if the name of destination file is not the same* The same as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc for [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) says:

> Warning If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.

If you need a different behavior have a look at [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and its `$mode` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**All these are form the [`w3schools`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_copy.asp)**

> The `copy()` function copies a file. This function returns TRUE on
>   success and FALSE on failure.
>
> **Note:** If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.

**Tips:** If you don't want to upload the same file or overrides then you can check for the file is exists or not if not then copy.

The `file_exists()` function checks whether or not a file or directory exists.

Details about [`file_exists`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_exists.asp)